# Maintain separate class files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have to admit that I am fairly a newbie to python. This question is more related to code organization.

For example, here is app.py file

```
import backtracker as bt
# Create a class

class TestTracker(bt.Strategy):

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        ''' Logging function for this strategy '''
        dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
        print('%s, %s' % (dt.isoformat(), txt))

    def __init__(self):
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].close
        self.datapoint = self.datas[0]

    def next(self):
        self.log('Close, %2f' %self.dataclose[0])
```

Now, I would like to separate class file to testStrategy.py and import it into app.py. The folder structure would look something like this

```
|
|-strategies
| |-testStrategy.py
|-app.py
```

How do I reference base class `bt.strategy` in my new class file ?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try what you have?

Comment: @DavidZ I am getting an error `bt.strategy` is not available in the class file which is true. My problem is passing `bt.strategy` to this new class file.

Comment: And this error does not occur when all the code is in `app.py`?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question. Where is backtracker located?

Comment: @DavidZ Yes. That's true.

Comment: @nightgaunt backtracker is a custom python module written by my coworker that I should be using.

Comment: What I meant: is it a package that can be imported anywhere in your project? Or is it defined in `app.py`?

Comment: @nightgaunt It is a package that can be imported anywhere. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: I am really not sure what is the problem here. if `backtracker` can be imported anywhere, that includes your testStrategy.py as well. So `import backtracker as bt` should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about it.

Add the folder strategies to `sys.path` and then import your class.

```
# This gives you the folder in which current file resides
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    if BASE_DIR + '/strategies' not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(BASE_DIR + '/strategies')
    from testStrategy import TestTracker
```

Add `__init__.py` in every folder and then use your code as a python package. This allows you to import in the following way.

```
import strategies.testStrategy.TestTracker
```

Be wary of the [trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html) though.